# Javascript fails to execute in headless Firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, headless

I've setup a Ubuntu Server install with Firefox 3.6.22 and installed a headless test environment using the headless and watir-webdriver Ruby gems. When testing in desktop browser all seems to work but in the headless Firefox version the javascript just stops dead. Normal javascript pages work and load correctly, any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 2):

Took a lot of debugging but it turns out that any console.log statements in your javascript will kill the headless firefox dead. Will investigate more to see if it's the old Ubuntu Firefox version or somewhere else in the chain.

Comment: `console.log` is only available as a built-in Firefox feature since 4.0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.log. Before that it was only provided by Firebug.